# How to get the touch position and remove background from image on android?

Tags: java, android, image, opencv, kotlin

I am using the manual selection of the touch on the screen so that the user can choose the region of interest to remove the background. For this I am developing an application in Kotlin using opencv. The way you are currently performing this removal with just two touch of the user on the screen, forming a square in the selection area. This works well for small images, but large images, the background clipping does not work well. For this, the best solution would be to get these coordinates with the free selection of the image, where the user can mark the entire border of the region of interest. Can someone help me make this change in my code. The code below is making the image selection and cropping the back.

[image]

[image]

COde:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    check(OpenCVLoader.initDebug(), { Toast.makeText(this, "OpenCV was not initialized properly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() })

    rxPermissions = RxPermissions(this)

    image.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
        if (!isPhotoChosen()) {
            return@setOnTouchListener false
        }
        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            val bounds = getBitmapPositionInsideImageView(image)
            val xScaled = (event.x / bounds[4]) - bounds[0]
            val yScaled = (event.y / bounds[5]) - bounds[1]
            if (!hasChosenTopLeft()) {
                coordinates.first.apply {
                    x = xScaled.toDouble()
                    y = yScaled.toDouble()
                }
            } else if (!hasChosenBottomRight()) {
                with(Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.width, bitmap.height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)) {
                    coordinates.second.apply {
                        x = xScaled.toDouble()
                        y = yScaled.toDouble()
                    }
                    val rectPaint = Paint().apply {
                        setARGB(255, 0, 255, 0)
                        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
                        strokeWidth = 4f
                    }
                    Canvas(this).apply {
                        drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, 0f, null)
                        drawRect(coordinates.first.x.toFloat(), coordinates.first.y.toFloat(), coordinates.second.x.toFloat(), coordinates.second.y.toFloat(), rectPaint)
                    }
                    image.setImageDrawable(BitmapDrawable(resources, this))
                }

            } else {
                resetTarget()
            }
        }
        true
    }
}
```